# How to use Html.DropDownListFor to create a DropDownList from a list of strings in VB.NET ASP.NET MVC

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have created a list of strings in my model class that I want to be a drop down list in my view so the user can choose only one option. The number of strings in my list will vary each time. I am struggling to understand what the parameters of the html helper is asking for. I have tried just using my list of strings as some of the parameters, which I thought would work because List implements IEnumerable, but didn't. I am having trouble finding examples online written in vb.net (most are in C#).

I was hoping someone could give me a better explanation about what DropDownListFor is asking for parameterwise as well as point me in the right direction of how I should go about coding a dropdownlist from a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

*I apologize, but my VB is kind of rusty, but hopefully this accommodates. I realize the nomenclature is a bit different in VB, but hopefully this gets you in the ballpark (or maybe someone will edit my post and supply a VB.NET version).*

Assuming you mean "list of strings" to be similar to:

```
IList<String> strings = new List<String> {
  "foo", "bar", "baz"
};
```

And maybe your model looks something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public String SelectedValue { get; set; }
  public IList<String> AvailableOptions { get; set; }
}
```

You can use something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
  x => x.SelectedValue,
  new SelectList(Model.AvailableOptions)
);
```

Which would then turn your `List<String>` into `SelectListOption`s and assign the selected value back to `SelectedValue`.

Of course if you want more control you can use LINQ:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
  x => x.SelectedValue,
  Model.AvailableOptions.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
    Text = x,
    Value = x,
    Selected = false // or whatever condition(s) you may have
   })
);
```

Comment: Your format/syntax does not look the same to whatever I am writing in my View.vbhtml. This is the method I am trying to use: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703670(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703670(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: It's going to be varied slightly given it's VB and not C#. For instance, you'll use things like `Function (x)` instead of c#'s lambdas (`x =>`)